# Bash скрипт. Команда MV и считывания пути с консоли

Tags: bash, unix, shell

Пользователь вводит с консоли имя файла и путь, куда необходимо переместить данный файл:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Input name of file";
read fileName;
echo "Input path";
read path;
mv $fileName $path;
```

Проблема заключается в том, что **$path** принимает как строку. То есть **mv** работает как переименовывание, а не как перемещение.

Как можно преобразовать **$path** в директорию?

Answer (score 4):

Это происходит если каталог `$path` не существует. Можно так:

```
mkdir -p "$path" && mv -t "$path" "$fileName"
```